# Angular - two dropdowns with same datasource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am having two dropdowns with same issue. my Challenge is , whenever i select 1 , the other one also gets selected. Also, if there is a validation error, it throws only on one dropdown. What am i missing?

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ctctype_id">
                       Current CTC
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="ctctype_id" id="ctctype_id" data-ng-model="formJobApplyData.salary_range"
                            data-ng-options="salary.key for salary in salaryList" data-validate-selected-keyvalue></select>
                </div>

                <div data-ng-messages="jobForm.ctctype_id.$error" data-ng-show="jobForm.ctctype_id.$invalid && (jobForm.ctctype_id.$touched || jobForm.ctctype_id.$dirty)" class="form-message">
                    <p data-ng-message="validselectedkeyvalue">
                        Please select your current CTC from the list
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exptype_id">
                       Expected CTC
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="expctc_id" id="expctc_id" data-ng-model="formJobApplyData.salary_range"
                            data-ng-options="salary.key for salary in salaryList" data-validate-selected-keyvalue></select>
                </div>

                <div data-ng-messages="jobForm.expctc_id.$error" data-ng-show="jobForm.expctc_id.$invalid && (jobForm.expctc_id.$touched || jobForm.expctc_id.$dirty)" class="form-message">
                    <p data-ng-message="validselectedkeyvalue">
                        Please select your expected CTC from the list
                    </p>
                </div>
```

My javascript Valiation :

```
app.directive('validateSelectedKeyvalue', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.validselectedkeyvalue = function (viewValue) {
                if (typeof (viewValue) != 'undefined') {
                    return ((typeof (viewValue.id) != 'undefined') && viewValue.id != 0) ? true : false;
                }
                else { return true; }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What's the point of two select boxes bound to the same ngModel? Or is that the problem? You shouldn't have two select boxes with the same ng-model. Also, isn't your validator basically the same thing as `required`?

Comment: As you can see.. they are serving two different purposes - one is to request for current salary and other one for expected salary. The list is the same. i can create two ng-models. but it will be duplicate.

Comment: If they serve different puposes, then they should be bound to different variables. You can't store two different salaries in a single salary variable. You need a variable for the current salary, and another for the expected salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason one drop-down is changing the other, is because they are bound to the same scope variable.

```
data-ng-model="formJobApplyData.salary_range"
```

I would suggest making one formJobApplyData.current_salary and one formJobApplyData.expected_salary.

This would also make sense that only one field is being validated. This is due to only one value is really being selected.

Comment: Thanks Sensok. Thats what i was guessing. i was thinking i could re-use the same model for both. Wil create two seperate entities

Comment: angular.copy does a great job with this.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - That would help if they were using two copies of the same datasources in the ng-options. But where the data should be two different models, you don't want to use angular.copy. You can use the same datasource for multiple dropdowns.

Comment: I think she's using the same model because the list of values is what she wants to reuse. So if she starts by creating a copy of the value she's using for salary into expectedSalary, she should get a value that has the options associated. Or she can just keep the salary options in a different variable altogether and not couple them to the salary.

Comment: @SenSok - Correct. That is what i did and it worked. i used the same datasource. just created another ng-model. Amy - The man is a he :)